# Is it possible for a non vegetarian to attain the birth of a devatās?

Tags: gods, rebirth

If a non vegetarian do a lot of charity and other good work, will he able to attain the birth of a devatās.

Or the birth of a devatās can only be achieved by a vegetarian who do the good karma as well.

Comment: 1). One of the *Kshatriya* kills the unjust out of his *dharmic* duty, while 2). another one kills the people, just out of his desires or pleasure or iffy. What do you think might happen in each case? Who'll get *Swarga* and who might be suffering?

Comment: @Vivikta it is not about humans it is about animals.

Comment: my argument point being, One **tends to eat** non-vegetarian food (which is an obvious, explicit form of *hinsa - violence*), out of material desires and avarice of the tongue, *वृत्ति - vritti*. Which is definitely not in accordance with the conduct required to be inducted for the post of a *devtaa*, I guess.

Comment: @Vivikta, well yes but there are many verses that says you eat meat (it allowes meat)

Comment: @Vivikta not just that meant that we eat today can be ahinsa as well. We don't cut meat by our own hands. We just buy them.

Comment: the texts **prescribes** not **commands*, **ONE MAY eat as per circumstances**. It's not authoritative maybe.

Comment: In any case, a sin is equally shared, the one to murders, the one who knows, the one who eats, the one who cooks, anyone related to the *hinsa* committed is told to be a sinner. And by that  "just eating and not killing logic ", the murder by a knife or gun is technically not committed by the person but the object. :p.

Comment: Also, read [this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2119/17833), it'll clear your doubt regarding the same. And maybe make this question of yours a possible duplicate of this same QnA.